# Restore Azure SQL Database from Another Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure-sql-database, database-restore

I'm not sure if this question has been asked because it's possible that I don't know how to ask the questino properly, but here goes...

I have two Azure SQL Databases.  One is for testing and one is for production.  In my CI/CD process, I would like to be able to take a copy of production (database) and restore it on top of the testing database.  Everything I've read explains how to delete the existing database and restore a dacpac file in it's place.  I don't want to do that because it's difficult as it is to create SQL user accounts and set permissions on them, so I would prefer to simply restore on top of the testing database.  Is that possible with Azure SQL Databases?  If so, could someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is not possible. If you restore from a bacpac or restore from automated backups it will always create a new database as result of the restore.  Have you tried to create your test database using CREATE DATABASE AS COPY OF?

```
DROP DATABASE MyTestDB;
CREATE DATABASE MyTestDB AS COPY OF MyProdDB;
```

Comment: Absolutely cannot believe it was as easy as that.  WOW!  Thank you so much for the quick fix.  This really did make my day.